# How to both autocomplete and limit to list with Delphi TComboBox

Tags: delphi, combobox, autocomplete

Suppose I want to select 'london' from a big list of UK towns

Setting

```
Combo1.AutoComplete := true;
Combo1.Style := csDropdown;
```

if I type 'l' followed by 'o', followed by 'n' it initially selects the first item starting with 'l' and then the first item starting with the two letters 'lo' and then the first starting with 'lon'. This is exactly the behaviour I want - which is good.

However I can also enter any text I like, whether it's in the list or not - this is bad.

Setting

```
Combo1.AutoComplete := true;
Combo1.Style := csDropdownList;
```

I can't enter any text I like but only select an item from the list - which is good.

But now if I type 'l' followed by 'o', followed by 'n' it initially selects the first item starting with 'l', then selects the first item starting with 'o' and the the first starting with 'n', instead of using all three letters and selecting the first item starting with 'lon'.

How can I achive both things at once?

ie I want to be limited to selecting items from the list but also be able to start typing and have it select on all the letters I have typed so far.

Comment: add an onexit event that checks if itemindex > 0, if not inform user?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that would help. If something gets selected then ItemIndex is always going to be > 0

Comment: If Style is csDropdown, user can enter anything he wants, check itemindex to see if he selected something from the list?

Comment: I have <select town> as item 0 so put
if combobox1.ItemIndex = -1 then
   combobox1.ItemIndex := 0;
in the OnExit event.

Sort of works but not very satisfactorily as the user can still enter anything. I'd really like non list items to be ignored

Comment: I think you might have it better for this if you use a `TDBLookupCombobox` instead. You only need to populate the `list items`. It will do what you want, although (at least in my tests) while it behaved as you want it did not show the partial string entered.

Comment: Your option 2 works for me. I put it as csDropDownList, then start typing "lon" and it goes to whatever starts with "lon". I'm using D7. What version are you using?

Comment: I tried a DBcomboBox and it did look like it was operating as I wished but now I can see that you can ONLY select an item by starting to type. Clicking an item does not select it. ie typing 'Bol' moves you to 'Bolton' but you can't then click on the town after Bolton (ie Boltongate). You have to type the 'g' as well ie all of 'Boltong' to reach it.

Comment: @GabrielF I'm using Delphi 2009. I think I might have found the reason. Using option 2 above as you suggested but increased the autocomplete delay from the default 500 to 5000. That seems to then give me time to type a few letters before it assumes the letter just typed is a new initial letter. Is this just a fluke or is this likely to be the answer?

Comment: 5s is a bit too much, I think. The 500ms default is good enough for me, maybe you could try 750 or something like that. But if you misstype a key, you'll have to wait 5s to start over. This would be unnacceptable for me, as a user.

Comment: @GabrielF. OK, How do I accept a comment (yours) as the answer?

Comment: You can't accept a comment as answer. But your comment is the real answer, so you could post it as a (self-)answer and mark it as accepted. My comment is just a comment, really. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the second option

```
Combo1.AutoComplete := true;
Combo1.Style := csDropdownList;
```

and increase the autocomplete delay from the default 500 to something a little bigger to give the user time to type the second and third etc characters before the autocomplete kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is small "hack" to control text in the ComboBox in code:

```
uses ... StrUtils;

...

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
  s, t: string;
  i, l: Integer;
  f: Boolean;
begin
  // Skip functional keys
  if Key < ' ' then
    Exit;

  // Get text which can be in the combo after key pressed
  i := ComboBox1.SelStart;
  l := ComboBox1.SelLength;
  t := ComboBox1.Text;
  s := Copy(t, 1, i) + Key + Copy(t, i + l + 1, Length(t));

  // Check is this text corresponds to the values list
  f := False;
  for i := 0 to ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
    if StrUtils.StartsStr(s, ComboBox1.Items[i]) then
    begin
      f := True;
      Break;
    end;

  // If not - cancel key
  if not f then
    Key := #0;
end;
```

PS: It is for `Combo1.Style := csDropdown;` case

Comment: Thanks but I think I might stick to GabrielF's comment and my comment back to him. The combo has about 40,000 towns in it so the whole point was to reach a particular town quickly. Having it search through all 40,000 towns every time a key is pressed (as well as presumably having the internals of the combo box do the same thing) would be a bit slow.