# Type ahead TComboBox csDropDownList; Delphi 10

Tags: delphi, tcombobox

When forcing the user to select from the dropdownlist,
I set the combobox' style to csDropDownlist. 
[image]

However, all typing hereafter is one character only.
That means, the user cannot narrow the search in the combo by typing multiple characters.  Not usefull, then.

When setting style to csDropDown, you can type multiple characters to narrow your search, 
[image]

but then you are not forced to select from the list any longer

[image]

Is there a way to combine these behaviours?

Comment: Just tested in Delphi 2007 (don't have a newer version at hand right now) - in a csDropDownList Combobox I can type `Item<space>4` and it will correctly select that element. Is this not the desired behaviour? Am I missing something?

Comment: _"Is there a way to combine these behaviours?"_ Yes. Stop typing :) Or ensure the user cannot type anymore when there's no item to match. You simply cannot select an item that doesn't exist.

Comment: The behaviour is as you want, but there are caveats. If you press I several times it will go down the list one by one. If you type the text *quickly enough* it will behave the way you want. If you type too slowly it will act the way you describe. I think that this is windows behaviour so shouldn't be Delphi version dependant.

Comment: Yep, control already behaves as you wish, at least for a VCL combo box

Comment: @David, no, it doesn't. Desired behavior seems to be free writing in a combo edit so long as the text matches an item in the combo list. Otherwise I cannot combine those two styles.

Comment: Have you tried setting AutoCompleteDelay to a higher value?

Comment: I tried changing autocompletedelay, it did not help.

Comment: I also tried Delphi 7, it behaves the same way...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your inputs.

I found a workaround here: 
[How to both autocomplete and limit to list with Delphi TComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28810151/how-to-both-autocomplete-and-limit-to-list-with-delphi-tcombobox)
that I have modified a bit:

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
 s, t: string;
i, l: Integer;
const CrLf = #13#10;
begin
 // Skip functional keys
 if Key < ' ' then
  Exit;

  key := upcase(key);

  // Get text which can be in the combo after key pressed
  i := ComboBox1.SelStart;
  l := ComboBox1.SelLength;
  t := ComboBox1.Text;
  s := Copy(t, 1, i) + Key;

  // Check is this text corresponds to the values list

  if pos(CrLf+s, CrLf+combobox1.Items.Text) > 0 then
  exit;


  Key := #0;
end;
```

Now it works exactly as hoped, but I have not tested with long itemlists yet.

But thank you to all.

Comment: Think about clipboard pasting as well.